# fail to call a function in another one with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call a function in another one.

The function to be called returns true or false:

```
$scope.verifsubdir = function(dir, tocheck) {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: '/checkIsSubdir/'+dir+'/'+tocheck})
    .success(function(result) {
        return result.data;
    })
    .error(function(result) {
        console.log("checksubdir oops");
    });
};
```

The function call in another function:

```
$scope.CopyFiles = function(destination) {
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.list.length; i++) {
        console.log($scope.verifsubdir($scope.list[i],destination));
    };
}
```

But I always get `undefined`.

However, when I merge the two functions I get true or false:

```
$scope.CopyFiles=function(destination){
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.list.length; i++){
        $http({method: 'GET', url:  
            '/checkIsSubdir/'+$scope.list[i]+'/'+destination})
        .success(function(result) {
            console.log("checkdir "+result.data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("checksubdir oops");
        });
    }
};
```

**I want them to be separated. How to fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

In the `$http` call returns a promise, your should do something like this:

```
$scope.verifsubdir($scope.list[i],destination).then(function(resp) {
   console.log(resp);
   // assuming the response returns a boolean
   $scope.list[i].verified = resp
});
```

Comment: check your code, seems like you missed some letters

Comment: Yup, I'm helpless without sublime apparently

Answer (score 0):

Using `$http` from Angular gives you a Promise back (you can read more about them in [the documentation for $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)), and won't make your function return any value on its own (this is why you get `undefined`).

Your first function will need to return the promise and then you would need to add additional `.success(...)` or `.error(...)` callbacks inside your `CopyFiles` function:

```
$scope.verifsubdir = function (dir, tocheck) {
  // Simply add return in front of $http here.
  return $http(...
};

$scope.CopyFiles = function (destination) {
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.list.length; i++) {
    $scope.verifsubdir($scope.list[i], destination).success(function (result) {
      console.log("checkdir " + result.data);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: thank you  , I think that doesn't change much comparing to merging the two functions .  Moreover when the result.data is true I want to do an instruction using `$scope.list[i]` but when testing  
`console.log($scope.list[i]);`  inside `.success` I get undefined